# The color grey eg,#f9f9f9 or other light color greys do not show on my mac book pro 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, color, gpu

The color grey eg,#f9f9f9 or other light color greys do not show on my mac book pro 2011.

I have turned off the automatic graphic switching,

and have also tried switching graphics cards around "Intel Graphics 3000" & "AMD Radeon 6490mb" using GFX Card Staus, but this has no effect.

I was thinking it could be a sensor on my mac im not aware of?? ,,depending how sunny it is??

It is really annoying, esp when designing things it makes it difficult to choose subtle grey colors.

Has anyone else ever had this issue or does anyone have a solution?

Comment: the other thing is sometimes the light grey colors do show, but mostly do not... which makes it extra annoying

Comment: Has the contrast setting that is shown in the accessibility preference pane been changed?

Comment: Hi, Thanks yes it has. I put it back down to normal and it shows the color correctly!! Thanks this has been annoying me for the last few months.

Comment: How does it change? is it an automated control?

Comment: also after a bit of reading shortcut keys are

Decrease display contrast: Command+Option+Control+commer
Increase display contrast: Command+Option+Control+peroid